# Python - speeding up debugging

Tags: python, performance, debugging, pycharm

For scripts that take a while to run, the slowdown from attaching the debugger can be a bit of a problem. In my case, it takes an hour to get to the first breakpoint.

I use PyCharm, which as far as I can tell uses the PyDev debugger - at least for remote debugging.  But the question should be just as relevant for other IDE's/debuggers.  (Personally, I would install another IDE if it would help with this problem.)

Is it possible to attach the debugger after the script has been running normally for a while? Then the first part of the code, where I don't need any debugging, would run much faster.

Any other ways to speed up debugging (without resorting to print statements and running without the debugger)?

Comment: What about `import pdb/ipdb/pudb; pdb/ipdb/pudb.set_trace()` right before the errorneous line? These are terminal-based debuggers.

Comment: @kroolik: That seems like it might do it! I will experiment with it and report findings here.

Comment: as @kroolik said. Just import before where you expect it to debug, and use a context manager to do so.

Comment: The suggested approach seems to solve the problem.  I am able to run the code normally until the breakpoint.  I have mostly just used the built-in debugger in PyCharm, and would have preferred if I could activate that rather than pdb etc, but using pdb is well worth it because of the saved time.  @GamesBrainiac: It would be interesting to see an example of using a context manager for this like you mention...